# Redirect to previous non drupal page after login

Tags: redirection, users

I have installed Drupal 7 on azeem.com, and I have installed a forum software on azeem.com/qa. I am trying to use Drupal as single sign on site.

When I am at azeem.com/qa, and I click on login page, it takes me to the Drupal login page with a URL like http://azeem.com/user/login?redirect=qa%2Findex.php%3Fq%3Dnode.

After giving the username and password, I successfully logged in, but instead of redirecting me back to http://azeem.com/qa, it takes me to http://azeem.com/user/1.

How can I redirect back to the page where I was before logging in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal doesn't react by default to a URL parameter called `redirect`; it does however react to the parameter `destination`. The `destination` parameter pretty much trumps any other internal redirect so this should override the default redirect.

When you send your users through to the Drupal login form try using a URL like this:

```
http://azeem.com/user/login?destination=qa
```